# Pass C# List to C++ CLI List and convert to vector

Tags: c#, c++-cli

Problem statement:  I wish to pass a generic list in C# to C++/CLI with the ability to also then convert the List in C++/CLI to a std::vector

In C# I have class

```
public class EtchVect
{

    public double XCoordinate { get; set; }
    public double YCoordinate { get; set; }
    public string LayerName { get; set; }

}
```

So then mock up would look like this:

```
List<EtchVect> etchVects = new List<EtchVect>();
etchVects.Add(new EtchVect() {LayerName = "C2", XCoordinate = 42.44, YCoordinate = 563.99});
```

Now I wish to receive the List in C++/CLI 
Should I create a class in C++ with properties ?
How can C++ CLI accept the List from C#? 
I also wish to then have a function in C++ to convert the List to a std::vector

I am sure this stuff has been done by others many times over, it is just unfamiliar territory for me (C++) and I seem to come up short with google searches and book searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The public interfaces of your C++/CLI application are a contract. This contract has to be known by both parties. You don't define the class on both ends, but use one assembly to define them and reference this assembly in both dll and program.

As your C++/CLi dll is probably already referenced in you C# project, define your class there in the public interface and use it from your C# application.